# how to pass FileInputStream through XSSFWorkbook constructor

Tags: selenium

Here is my selenium code to set excel file 
 ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
error is The constructor XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined

Can any one tell me why is it so...
how to pass FileInputStream here. am using  poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5

Comment: it should be new XSSFWorkbook(new File(ExcelFile path));

Comment: I have tried those code,  but it's not working. @santhosh kumar

Comment: FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Excel path);

   // Access the required test data sheet

   ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

Comment: This is the code i tried first 
FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Excel path); ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

Comment: File path1 = new File(Excel path); FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path1); new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

Comment: public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {  try {          
                           File Path1 = new File(Path); 
                    FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path1); 
                    ExcelWBook= new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile); 
                    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                    Log.info("Excel sheet opened");
                    } 
                   catch (Exception e){
                     //ExcelFile.close();
                        throw (e);
                    }
            }

Comment: what is the err that you are getting?

Comment: The constructor XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined

Comment: Can you paste your complete code and err message and update the question?